# Symbol table entry for templates

Tags: c++, unix

I have doubt about template functions. 
If i write a normal function like

```
int function1(int x);
int function1(int x, int y);
```

two symbol table entry will be made for function1.
each entry represents each overloaded function.

In case of template function, what exactly happens and how it is handled by the compiler.

```
template<class X>
int function1(X a);
```

How many symbol table entries will be present for template functions?

Comment: Probably one for each instantiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "template function" in C++. There are "function templates," that is, templates (or perhaps blueprints) for creating functions. Once you accept this, the answer becomes easier to discover.

A template is purely a compilation construct. Each *function* instantiated from the template is (naturally) a function and thus it will have its own symbol.

Just as with `inline` functions, if one and the same function (= using the same set of template arguments) is instantiated from the template in different translation units (= different .cpp files), the compiler & linker must ensure these are merged into one, because their addresses must be the same. How they do it is an implementation detail of theirs; the standard just mandates that they have to do it. And I am afraid I don't know the technical details of how this can be done, so I can't provide an example.

Comment: I like this answer most, but it misses the part where multiple instantiations with the same template parameters will not create multiple functions (or they get fused together).

Comment: @nwp Unfortunately, I know precious little of how this actually works; I can add a general statement, but little more than that.

Comment: @nwp: Unfortunately, this is a question of its own, because the C++ Standard does not concern itself with the petty details (it just mandates the results). Merging them is a toolchain problem, and each toolchain is free to use whatever method they deem suitable to solve the issue.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Then this answer is now about as good as it can be. Nice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my problem is i have function template in a shared object and i want to use this function from shared object. If it is creating the symbolic reference once it encounters the function call, i cannot make use of templates in shared object. But how is this handles in standard c++ templates. This is what i want to know.

Comment: @suhastheju You shouldn't care about such implementation details as symbol table entries for this. Follow the standard: either an explicit instantiation is present, or the template definition must be available in each translation unit. That normally means templates are header-only, and that's how the standard library is (usually) implemented. If you can provide explicit instantiations in the shared object, do so. If you can't, define the template fully in a header file.

Comment: @Angew Thanks for your response. After putting function definition inside the header file the problem got resolved. Instantiating explicitly didn't worked for my case, as there were many cases to take care of.

Answer (score 0):

For sure "one for each instantiation".

```
A function template by itself is not a type, or a function, or any other entity.
No code is generated from a source file that contains only template definitions.
In order for any code to appear, a template must be instantiated: the template
arguments must be determined so that the compiler can generate an actual function
```

[link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template)

Comment: Still a bit short for an "answer".  There's more to say.  If you do not have to say more, you better just give comments.

Comment: Copying an example from someone else's answer, with no accompanying explanation, doesn't improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instance of the function template using specific template parameter, the compiler generates one overloaded method. So when you use the method

```
temlate<class X>
int function1(X a);
```

to use like

```
function1<int>(5);
function1<double>(5.0);
```

Compiler generates

```
int function1(int a);
int function1(double a);
```

These are overloaded and there will be 2 symbols.

In fact `templates` are much like `macro`, with strong type checking. At compile type function templates are replaced with actual instance. In `object` code there is no existence of the **template function**, only the instantiate overloads (if any).

Answer (score 0):

In the case that nobody is using the template to create a compiled function, in fact *no* entry is created in the symbol table.  Otherwise, for each different use of the template (for each type or type combination—in case there are several type parameters to it) one more compiled function and thus one more entry in the symbol table is created.

Templates are evaluated on compile time only; after compiling they do not exist anymore.